# Rearrange rows in a table using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html-table

Let's say I have 3 rows in my table like this:

```
$("tr").filter(function(){ return $(this).text() == '1'; }).text('One');
$("tr").filter(function(){ return $(this).text() == '2'; }).text('Two');
$("tr").filter(function(){ return $(this).text() == '3'; }).text('Three');
```

How do I re-arrange the rows so that row 3 will be on row 1?

Answer (score 0):

```
one = $("tr").filter(function(){ return $(this).text() == '1'; }).text('One');
two = $("tr").filter(function(){ return $(this).text() == '2'; }).text('Two');
three = $("tr").filter(function(){ return $(this).text() == '3'; }).text('Three');
one.before(three);
```

Comment: No, it does not work. The 3rd row does not move to the 1st row. I've tried different combinations like three.before(one) but nothing happens. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Hi wachK. Umm, not sure what you mean. Please explain.

Comment: I think the logic is right but the syntax is wrong. Can anyone please correct?

Comment: Never mind. I got it working. Instead of `one=$("tr")...` I did `one=$('tr:nth-child(1)');`.